# Cookie not accepting dynamic data ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, cookies

When using my Cookie, I have 2 buttons which should add a number to it.
Using that number I make it print a shopping cart.
But when I print it, it only gives 1 number back.
If I insert static data it does work, however when I press both buttons, it only seems to add 1 of the values.

Cookie being made:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["MyTestCookie"] == null)
        {
            HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("MyTestCookie");
            Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
            myCookie.Values.Add("", "1");
            myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30);
        }


    }
```

Buttonclick add data to cookie, got two of these, Button1 adds nr 3 and Button2 adds nr 2:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Cookies["MyTestCookie"].Values.Add("item", "3");
        Response.Write(Request.Cookies["MyTestCookie"].Values.ToString());
    }
```

Buttonclick check for data in cookie:

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cookies = Request.Cookies["MyTestCookie"].Values.ToString();
        Response.Write("Cookie: "+cookies);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cookies["MyTestCookie"].Values.Add("item", "3");
    Response.Cookies["MyTestCookie"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30);
    Response.Write(Request.Cookies["MyTestCookie"].Values.ToString());
}
```

Because the cookie was being destroyed when leaving this method. Setting expire time makes sure that it won't happen immediately.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, but I think this might be because cookies apparently can't add information on different buttons without overwriting the previous inserted value. Thanks for your help.

Comment: My bad. It's because you are not adding the previous value of the cookie when clicking the add button - it's overriding the previous one. 

Please try something like this:

    var currentItemValue = request.Cookies["MyTestCookie"]["item"];
    Response.Cookies["MyTestCookie"].Values.Add("item", currentItemValue + ","  + "3");

Comment: Thanks, it works fine now. I'm new to ASP.net so I thought Response would just add to the cookie, instead of deleting the old values.